# How can I use my own image for the boot splash screen?

Tags: boot, customization, plymouth

How can I create and use my own boot splash screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a four-part guide about Plymouth's script plugin (written by its author, a bit dated):

1. http://brej.org/blog/?p=158
2. http://brej.org/blog/?p=174
3. http://brej.org/blog/?p=197
4. http://brej.org/blog/?p=238

Themes are located in `/lib/plymouth/themes/`, I suggest you start with a copy of the ubuntu-logo theme and play around with it (following the guide).

---

To install your theme, run:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/<THEME>/<THEME>.plymouth 100`

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k all`

---

To test your theme within a desktop session, run:

`sudo plymouthd ; sudo plymouth --show-splash`

This should bring up two windows running your theme (to test multi-head setups and to check how the theme looks on smaller screens).

Answer (score 1):

You can also make your GRUB screen look nice by installing Burg.

Good tutorial for installing it [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/get-animated-themed-icon-only-grub-menu-using-burg-now-simple-to-use/).

Answer (score 1):

Try Ubuntu Tweak - it will let you customize the boot screen to any image you want.